# Como interagir campos de tabelas msql?

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu estou criando uma pagina de troca de livros, fiz duas tabelas a de desejos e meus. até a parte do desejo do usuário logado achar os livros dos outros eu consegui fazer, mas gostaria tb quero q os outros usuários tenha como desejo os livros do usuário logado. tipo: eu ter um livro A e desejar um B, e um outro usuário ter o B e desejar um A. Meu select q fiz até agora

```
   SELECT b.meu,b.autor, b.genero,b.userid, b.foto
      FROM desejos AS a 
      INNER JOIN meus AS b ON
        (CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', b.meu,'%')or
        CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', b.genero,'%')or
        CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', b.autor,'%'))
      WHERE
        a.userid = $_SESSION[id]
          AND
        b.userid != $_SESSION[id]
```

tentei colocar "and

```
   CONCAT('%', b.meu,'%') LIKE (CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%') or  
   CONCAT('%', b.genero,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%')or
   CONCAT('%', b.autor,'%') LIKE CONCAT('%', a.desejo,'%'))
```

mas n deu certo.
as tabelas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que não basta postar a SQL, você deve mostrar o esquema dessas tabelas. Livro é uma entidade? "meu" é uma relação (N pra N) com essa entidade? "desejo" é outra relação?

Comment: coloquei uma imagem das tabelas, no caso o desejo e meu são nomes de livros.

Comment: Na minha opinião, você deveria rever esse modelo ai, há algum motivo para não poder haver um identificador único para um livro(id)? você está usando o título para junção? Também não ficou claro qual é teu objetivo com esta query? o que exatamente você quer listar? todos os livros do usuário, e seus "desejos"?

Comment: os livros tem identificador único, só q com o id n da para comparar os titulos. Meu objetivo com esse select é retornar apenas os livros do usuário A deseje, que o usuário B tenha como desejo  pelo menos um livro do usuário A.